# Can stress-induced cortisol reduce diabetes type I?

Tags: autoimmune, diabetes-mellitus

Let us consider a patient with type 1 diabetes.

I think it would be safe to say that diabetes is an autoimmune disease. Now let us suppose this patient comes under stress. As far as I know, cortisol is a stress hormone and is released when a human is under stress. Now cortisol, as far as I know, increases the amount of blood sugar and at the same time is an immunosuppressant.

I would like to know whether this stress-induced cortisol can suppress the immune system, which has gone haywire, and help against diabetes - thereby rendering a suitable amount of stress useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**
Stress is not a good candidate to treat autoimmune disease like diabetes type I.

**Background**
Stress indeed [weakens the immune system](http://www.apa.org/research/action/immune.aspx), and diabetes type I is indeed caused by an [auto-immune response](http://www.diapedia.org/type-1-diabetes-mellitus/insulitis) against the insulin-producing beta cells in the islets of Langerhans. However, autoimmune diseases like diabetes type I need chronic treatment (i.e., [insulin treatment and dietary changes](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/type-1-diabetes/basics/treatment/con-20019573)).

Even if stress would help reduce diabetes type I (admittedly, theoretically it could), chronic stress would also reduce the immune response against viral and bacterial infections, it would reduce wound healing and perhaps even increase the risk of contracting cancer [(Glaser & Kiecolt-Glaser (2005)](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~scohen/JAMA_2007_Psy_Stress_Disease.pdf), as well as increase the risk of depression and cardiovascular disease [(Cohen *et al*., 2007)](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~scohen/JAMA_2007_Psy_Stress_Disease.pdf).

Hence, it is safe to say that deploying chronic stress as a treatment against auto-immune disease effectively means substituting one life-threatening condition with another.

<sup>**References**

**-** [Cohen *et al*., *JAMA* (2007); **298**(14): 1685-7](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~scohen/JAMA_2007_Psy_Stress_Disease.pdf)

**-** [Glaser & Kiecolt-Glaser, *Nature Rev Immunol* (2005); **5**: 243-51](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/type-1-diabetes/basics/treatment/con-20019573)</sup>

Comment: What about deliberately going through a little amount of stress everyday in a manner which is controlled enough to even reach up to the periphery of being chronic.

Comment: It is an idea, but I doubt anyone has tested it. Which patient would prefer to be stressed as opposed to regular treatment with insulin? Would you? Further, how to stress someone daily for years in a controlled way? I doubt anyone has tested it for these reasons.